Orthogonalization of exponential functions
I need to find a function $f(x,y)$ such that for any two integers $m,n>1$ there will be $$\int\limits_a^b m^{-x}n^{-y}f(x,y)\,dxdy=\delta_{m n}$$
Here the integration limits $a,b$ can be chosen arbitrarily, with $a≥ 0$ and $a<b≤\infty$.
It is important to remain on the positive half axis and not to go to imaginary exponentials, where the problem reduces to Fourier integral with some modifications, because the problem appears as a result of some asymptotic expansion which is valid only for real exponentials.
Seemingly there should appear Laguerre functions in some way, but I don't see how exactly.
Will be grateful for ideas.

So when you write the integral, are you saying the region of integration is $[a,b]^2$? Because you are supposed to have a double integral.

Yes, sure. The same integration area for both

For $0\le a<b<\infty$ such nonzero function $f(x,y)$ does not exist.  Indeed consider the linear span $\mathcal{A}$ of the functions $m^{-x}n^{-y},$ $n>m\ge 2.$ Then $\mathcal{A}$ forms a subalgebra of $C([a,b]\times [a,b]).$ Indeed $$(m_1^{-x}n_1^{-y})(m_2^{-x}n_2^{-y})=(m_1m_2)^{-x}(n_1n_2)^{-y} $$ The algebra does not vanish as  $2^{-x}3^{-y}\neq 0$ for all $x,y.$  The algebra separates points, as well. Indeed assume $$m^{-x_1}n^{-y_1} =m^{-x_2}n^{-y_2}$$ Then we get linear equalities $$ (\log m) (x_1-x_2)+(\log n)(y_1-y_2)=0$$  The equalities for $(m,n)=(2,3)$ and $(m,n)=(2,3^2)$ imply $x_1=x_2$ and $y_2=y_2.$
By the Stone- Weierstrass theorem $\mathcal{A}$ is dense in $C([a,b]\times [a,b]).$ Therefore $$\int\limits_a^b\int\limits_a^bg(x,y)f(x,y)\,dx\,dy =0$$ for any $g\in C([a,b]\times [a,b]).$ Hence $f=0.$
For $b=\infty$ we may use a generalization of the S-W theorem and get that $\mathcal{A}$ is dense in $C_0([a,\infty )\times [a,\infty ))$ consisting of functions which tend to $0$ when $x+y$ tends to infinity. In particular $C_0$ contains all compactly supported continuous functions. Therefore $f=0.$

@Aruralreader Thanks for spotting a misprint.
